# why boolean parameter is giving pipeline must contain at least one stage with no dependencies whereas string parameter doesn't give?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have below snippet in my azure Devops yml while I give is_exec_req parameter in if condition then it asks me the pipeline must contain at least one stage with no dependencies while if I change the parameter is_exec_req to string  and give something value "yes or no" then it doesn't give me this error. why?
Not working

```
parameters:
- name: is_exec_req
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: DependsOn
  type: object

stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_exec_req, 'false') }}:
  - stage: runhello
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.DependsOn)
    jobs:
    - job: hello
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          target type: inline
          script:
            echo "Hello"
```

working

```
parameters:
- name: is_exec_req
  type: string
  default: 'no'
- name: DependsOn
  type: object

stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_exec_req, 'no') }}:
  - stage: runhello
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.DependsOn)
    jobs:
    - job: hello
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          target type: inline
          script:
            echo "Hello"
```